# Stub dependent function with sinon and proxyquire does not print stub result

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon-chai

I wrote a unit test for _getuser() but I don't see console.log print stub result.Also test coverage shows line 'let user = result.user;
console.log('User'+JSON.stringify(result));' is uncovered.Why stub result does not print in console log in getUser() function in LogInCommand class.
I see result shows undefined in unit test.

```
// userApi.js

    'use strict';
    const config = require('../../config/config');
    const api = require('./apiService');

    class UserApi {
        constructor() {
        }
        getUser(userId) {
            return api.get({
                url: config.url,
                qs: {
                    includeInactive: true,
                    id: userId,
                    startIndex: 0,
                    maxResults: 1
                },
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json;',
                    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
                }
            });
        }

    }
    module.exports = UserApi;

    // LoginCommand.js

    'use restrict';

    const userApi = require('../../api/userApi');
    class LogInCommand {
        constructor() {
        }
        async _getUser(userId) {
            let result = await new userApi().getUser(userId);
            let user = result.user;
            console.log('User'+JSON.stringify(result));
            return user;
        }

    }

    module.exports = LogInCommand;

    //LoginCommand.test.js
    describe('Test LogInCommand Class',function(){
      it.only('_getUser function should return user',    async ()=> { 
            let apiData= {
                user:'abc'
            };
          let logincmd = proxyquire('../LogInCommand.js', {
                userApi : { getUser : Promise.resolve(apiData) },'@noCallThru':true});
            let obj= new logincmd();
            let result= await obj._getUser(client);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxyquire configuration is incorrect in your current setup. Proxyquire maps the string value passed in a require call to the desired mock/stub values. Try the following instead:

```
let logincmd = proxyquire('../LogInCommand.js', {
  '../../api/userApi' : { getUser : Promise.resolve(apiData) },
  '@noCallThru':true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, you suggestion worked for me with some code change

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me
// userApi.js

```
'use strict';
const config = require('../../config/config');
const api = require('./apiService');

class UserApi {
    constructor() {
    }
    getUser(userId) {
        return api.get({
            url: config.url,
            qs: {
                includeInactive: true,
                id: userId,
                startIndex: 0,
                maxResults: 1
            },
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json;',
                'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
            }
        });
    }

}
module.exports = UserApi;

// LoginCommand.js

'use restrict';

const userApi = require('../../api/userApi');
class LogInCommand {
    constructor() {
    }
    async _getUser(userId) {
        let result = await new userApi().getUser(userId);
        let user = result.user;
        console.log('User'+JSON.stringify(result));
        return user;
    }

}

module.exports = LogInCommand;

//LoginCommand.test.js
describe('Test LogInCommand Class',function(){
  it.only('_getUser function should return user',    async ()=> { 
        class userApiStub{
        constructor(){}
        getUser() {
            return  Promise.resolve({
                user:4
            });
        }
    }
      let logincmd = proxyquire('../LogInCommand.js', {
            '../../api/userApi' :userApiStub },'@noCallThru':true});
        let obj= new logincmd();
        let result= await obj._getUser(client);
    });

});
```